# win vista sp2 x64 still won't install

Tags: windows, windows-vista, 64-bit, installation, sp2

Since Vista SP2 came out I have been trying to update, unsuccessfully. I always go through the whole installation process, the system reboots, says it is in Step 3 of 3 and aborts with a message similar to "Service pack did not install. Reverting changes." and then presents me with my login/password to enter.

I have geniune Win Vista Home Premium x64 SP1 in a Gateway P-7811FX PC.

I have done most of what is mentioned in this link: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasp/thread/f7fb0ace-eedb-483a-8614-f7c2cbca6ccf

My latest system error log shows:

`Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x80070002: Windows Vista Service Pack 2 for x64-based Systems (KB948465).`

Details:

`- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">

- <System>

  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient" Guid="{945a8954-c147-4acd-923f-40c45405a658}" />

  <EventID>20</EventID>

  <Version>0</Version>

  <Level>2</Level>

  <Task>1</Task>

  <Opcode>13</Opcode>

  <Keywords>0x8000000000000028</Keywords>

  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2009-08-25T19:54:19.812Z" />

  <EventRecordID>141578</EventRecordID>

  <Correlation />

  <Execution ProcessID="988" ThreadID="3712" />

  <Channel>System</Channel>

  <Computer>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</Computer>

  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />

  </System>

- <EventData>

  <Data Name="errorCode">0x80070002</Data>

  <Data Name="updateTitle">Windows Vista Service Pack 2 for x64-based Systems (KB948465)</Data>

  <Data Name="updateGuid">{CDD98232-6749-4E45-B06A-69E5BF8D48FE}</Data>

  <Data Name="updateRevisionNumber">106</Data>

  </EventData>

  </Event>`

Short of reinstalling the whole thing, does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Tried getting the standalone from http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/ and did the process again, now the errors in Event Viewer show as: "Windows Servicing failed to complete the process of setting package Package_for_KBXXXXXX_client_X~XXXXXXXXXXX~amd64~~6.0.1.0 () into Staged(Staged) state" and "Windows Servicing failed to complete the process of setting package Package_9_for_KBXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXX~amd64~en-US~6.0.1.18005 () into Staged(Staged) state"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so I FINALLY got to install this frigging service pack!

what did it:

1. In case something goes wrong: BACKUP and have all your hardware drivers INSIDE your hard disk drive (in case you lose CDROM or web access).
2. download the standalone installer from http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/ (IE only, obviously)
3. do an in-place upgrade as described by Matt H in http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistahardware/thread/95b8cb0f-9d2f-4f3d-b28b-aeb731c5c90c
4. step two took more than three hours in my machine. Once finished it may not recognize some of your hardware. IGNORE any "find a driver for this hardware" message. Just go ahead and run the SP2 installer.

After about 30/40 minutes I finally got the "Windows Vista Service Pack 2 is now installed" window. No rollbacks, no hassle. If any hardware is still unrecognized just go through your normal driver install.

Just so you do not miss Matt H's explanation of in-place upgrade here it goes:

> You can upgrade in-place, which means you can install Windows Vista and retain your applications, files, and settings as they were in your previous edition of Windows. An In-Place upgrade is actually a repair installation using the upgrade option. If you have installed Service Pack 1 for Windows Vista and your original Windows Vista DVD does not include this Service Pack, then the Upgrade option will be disabled, thus preventing you from doing an in place upgrade. The reason for this is that, by installing Service Pack 1 your system is, in effect, newer than that of your original Vista DVD (the only exception to this is if you have a slipstreamed copy of Windows Vista including Service pack 1).
>
> So, if your original Windows Vista DVD does not contain Service Pack 1 you will need to Uninstall Service Pack 1 from your PC prior to attempting the upgrade.
>
> Note: After performing In-Place Upgrade, your personal data and installed programs will not be removed but we may need to run Windows Update to install all the available updates for your system to update these system files to the current version. This troubleshooting process is time consuming and may take several hours to complete.
>
> If you would like to perform the In-place Upgrade, refer to the following steps.
>
> 1. Start the computer by using the current Operating System.
> 2. Insert the Windows Vista DVD in the computer's DVD drive.
> 3. Use one of the following procedures, as appropriate:
>
> • If Windows automatically detects the DVD, the Install now screen appears. Click Install now.
>
> • If Windows does not automatically detect the DVD, follow these steps:
>
> a. Click Start, click Run, type Drive:\setup.exe, and then click OK. Note Drive is the drive letter of the computer's DVD drive.
>
> b. Click Install now.
>
> 4. When you reach the "Which type of installation do you want?" screen, click Upgrade to upgrade the current operating system to Windows Vista.
> 5. Please run Windows Update again as you will need to download and install the most current updates.
>
> If you do not have the Windows Vista Installation DVD, I suggest contacting your PC manufacturer or our Customer Service to order a backup disk.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a KB article from MSFT.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/910336

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910336
You get a 0x80070002 error code which that link describes how to resolve.

Comment: Thanks

1) I don't have an "Automatic updates" service so I stopped "Windows Update"
2) stopped antivirus etc.
3) did the process: no luck, same message in logs although I noticed a warning in there: "Windows Servicing identified that package KB948465(Service Pack) is not applicable for this system" and an info "Windows Servicing started a process of changing package KB948465(Service Pack) state from Staged(Staged) to Staged(Staged)" repeated dozens of times in the last 2/3 minutes (although it just might be how Win works I guess)